# How to store meta data on a struct?

Tags: rust

Is there a way in Rust to store meta data for a struct without changing its fields?

I want to write a library that uses a macro to store meta data about the struct which can be writable at runtime.

Traits allow me to define accessor functions but I do not think they will let me store state?

I want to store state per struct instance.

In JS I might store this state in a closure or with a WeakMap (so the meta data is attached to the object but does not change its keys).

I think the only way to do this is  to wrap the struct in another MetaData struct, but I would prefer just passing around the original struct and using trait methods to read/write the data.

Thanks.

Comment: A weak hash table ?

Comment: I didn't understand a thing, you talk about metadata then state, trat, weak hashmap, that random choice of key word is not helping

Comment: @Stargateur associating data to objects without modifying the objects themselves is commonly done by using a WeakKeyMap keyed on the object, with the metadata / additional data as value. In fact I'm pretty sure that's the main if not only reason and use case for JS's WeakMap (which is weak on the key).

Comment: @coredump because Rust is ownership-based, a weakmap is not really a thing. If all the objects were behind Rc/Arc (which is constraining) then you could try to key on the `Weak`, but `Weak` is neither `Hash + Eq` nor `Ord`, so you'd have to key on the raw pointer to the T (not to the raw weak pointer as they're all different), while keeping the Weak (possibly in raw form) around to check if it's still alive (and periodically un-retain "dead" weakrefs), or alternatively implement a wrapper type which implements Hash + Eq in those terms (using `Weak::as_ptr` and `Weak::ptr_eq`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way in Rust to store meta data for a struct without changing its fields?

Not really, to be honest. Unless the struct is always stored behind an `Rc` or `Arc` then I guess you could create a map keyed on the weak pointers, which you'd regularly reap by removing the weak pointers whose strong pointer is dead, something along the lines of [this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39197ba5710a87e33bbf7f58f7d5ab7d).

> In JS I might store this state in a closure or with a WeakMap (so the meta data is attached to the object but does not change its keys).

You could do something along those lines if you `Pin` the structure in memory (and associate your metadata to the memory location of your structure), however unlike a proper weakmap the memory will pretty much be leaked as you'll have no way to get notified of the object being destroyed (as far as I know, unlike C++ Rust doesn't provide for custom drop in `Box`, or in `Pin`).

There are also wildly unsafe tricks with heap allocations where you allocate more than asked and store the metadata *before* the pointer you return (and the thing you're asked to allocate after). I know that it's somewhat common in C (e.g. that's how antirez' SDS provides safer C-compatible strings, [the length field is stored alongside the string buffer but before the pointee location](https://github.com/antirez/sds#how-sds-strings-work)), but I don't know if there is any Rust package which handles that.